# React.createElement throws Component not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm currently playing around with `ReactJS` using `TypeScript` as the underlying language wher I define my components.

I saw on many sites, that it is possible to render such components within a page (in my case `cshtml`). Especially [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters/ASPNET-Monsters-94-React-with-Server-Side-Rendering) which I tried to accomplish.
To do so there should be something like:

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <div id="myTargetId"></div>
</body>
<!-- ... -->

<script src="@(Url.Content("~/Scripts/React/dist/commons.js"))"></script>
<script src="@(Url.Content("~/Scripts/React/dist/MyComponent.js"))"></script>
<script>
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyComponent, {}), document.getElementById("targetId"));
</script>
```

Currently I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyComponent is not defined

This is what my `MyComponent.tsx` looks like:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface IMyComponentProps { }
export interface IMyComponentState { }

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMyComponentProps, IMyComponentState> {
    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <p>This comes from ReactJs</p>
        );
    }
}
```

To pack this all together I am using `webpack` with the following `webpack.config.js` (simplified):

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        MyComponent: "./Scripts/React/Modules/MyComponent.tsx"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./Scripts/React/dist/"),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },

    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

And, finally, this is the emitted `JavaScript`:

```
webpackJsonp([0],[
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const React = __webpack_require__(1);
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (React.createElement("p", null, "This comes from ReactJs"));
    }
}
exports.MyComponent = MyComponent;


/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = React;

/***/ })
],[0]);
//# sourceMappingURL=MyComponent.js.map
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think you should use default export- `export default class MyComponent`. i'm not using typescript nor react.net hence i'm not sure

Comment: If I write `export default ChallengerTeamDetails;` at the end of the `tsx` it's get emitted to `exports.MyComponent= MyComponent;
exports.default = MyComponent;` but still it's not working

Comment: Post the code where you import MyComponent.

Comment: @skypecakes I don‘t import anywhere. The website I had this from did not mention this. On the other hand they not used webpack. I've also added the link to the question

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyComponent is not defined

Your import is wrong:

```
<script src="@(Url.Content("~/Scripts/React/dist/commons.js"))"></script>
<script src="@(Url.Content("~/Scripts/React/dist/MyComponent.js"))"></script>
```

You should be building a `bundle.js` using webpack.

## More

One of many quickstarts on the internet https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: I do already. It's the same as in the link you've posted. It's only named different `[name].js` which will resolve to `MyComponent.js` instead of `bundle.js`, no?